# Formatting tsx files in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jhipster

Is there a good plugin for auto formatting and highlighting TypeScript (.tsx) files in a JHipster React project ? There seems to be no highlighting applied at all with the default installation

Comment: Are you using Community or Ultimate edition?

Comment: When using IDEA Ultimate, no plugins are required, this should work out of the box